# Bingo number class: receiving errors

Tags: java, performance, compiler-errors

The goal of this project is to create a host program that manages a Bingo game. Each round of game, there can be a number of players. In a round of the game, a player can have any number of Bingo cards. I need to create different classes that feed into my main method. Right now I am working on my Bingo number class and the purpose of this is to get a Bingo number which can be marked by a player. I keep getting int cannot be dereferenced error. Here is my code:

```
public class BingoNumber
{
   private int number;
   private boolean [][] mark;
   private int [][] card;

 //Constructor constructs an object of type BingoNumber 
 public BingoNumber(int aNumber)
 {
    card = new int [5][5];
    for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
    for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
    card[r][c]=(int)(Math.random()*75+1);

    mark = new boolean [5] [5];
    for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
    for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
    mark[r][c] = false;

    number = aNumber;
 }
//returns the integer representing the number of the BingoNumber. 
public int getNumber() 
{
    return number;
}
//returns true or false whether the number is marked
public boolean isMarked() 
{
    for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
    for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
    if(card[r][c] == number)
    {
        mark[r][c] = true;  
        return mark[r][c];
    }
    else
        return mark[r][c];
}
/*returns a two-digit string presentation of a BingoNumber. 
 The output string depends on whether the number is marked. 
 If the number is not marked yet, shows the number. 
 If the number is marked, the output string will XX. **/
public String toString() 
{   
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder ();
    s.append(number);
    //getting int cannot be dereferenced
    s.append("XX" + number.isMarked()); 
    return s.toString();
}
/*Returns a two-digit string representation of a BingoNumber 
  as if it has not been marked yet.*/
public String toNumberString() 
{
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder ();
    s.append(number);
}
//Notes that once the number is marked it cannot be unmarked. 
/*Later in a future class there will be method that will 
  let users unmark a Bingo number.*/
public void mark()    
{
    for (int i = 0; i < card.length; i++)
    //int cannot be dereferenced
    card[i][i].isMarked(number); 
}
```

}

Comment: receiving errors, can you post the exact errors? what exactly do you want this line to do? card[i][i].isMarked(number);

Comment: I was attempting to create a method that once a bingo number as been marked it can't be changed. Syntax error I recieved is int cannot be deferenced in my toString method and mark method.

Comment: well,you are trying to call isMarked on an int. isMarked is an instance method of BingoNumber

Comment: Okay, I'm unsure how to fix that.

Comment: you'll need to re-think your entire code. which objects to use, where to use them, ...